# Difference between "if (foo) bar();" and "foo && bar();"

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between the following two snippets, or any reason to use one over the other?

```
if (foo) {
    bar();
}
```

```
foo && bar();
```

Comment: The 1st is more traditional. Effectively, they're the same, though.

Comment: No difference but I prefer one line `if` statements. `if (foo) bar();`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The second form is known as [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and results in exactly the same as the first form. However the first form is more readable and should be preferred for maintainability.

This type of short-cuircuit evaluation is often seen in if-statements, where the right hand is conditionally evaluated. See the example below; **bar** is only evaluated if foo evaluates to true.

```
if (foo && bar()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It is not exactly the same, in the sense of grammar. (*expression* vs *statement*)

Answer (score 3):

The version `foo && bar()` is an expression, and thus has a value:

```
var result = foo && bar();
```

When using the `if` version, the above might look like this:

```
var result;
if (foo) {
    result = bar();
}
```

which is more verbose.

Comment: Actually `foo && bar();` is a statement, not expression, `foo && bar()` is an expression.

Comment: @zch Correct. It is an [expression statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.4).

Comment: the if-version is not correct; if foo is falsy, that falsy value is returned. Thus `else { result = foo; }`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of bouke with the short-cuircuit evaluation is really good. But I like to add that a good coding style is the use of the if-statement, if the call of bar() has no boolean-return-value and no further condition has to be satisfied using bar().