# Using && as a replacement for IF statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, readability

I found the following snippet when digging through some code:

```
"string" != typeof myVar && (myVar = "");
```

I understand what happens here. If myVar is not a string, that first condition evaluates to true so the second condition is evaluated, causing myVar to be set to "". So it's essentially a replacement for the following:

```
if ("string" != typeof myVar)
    myVar = "";
```

The only discernible difference is that the former of the two strategies is also a return statement, though the code I found is not using the returned value. So I'm wondering:

1. Are there any pros or cons to either strategy?
2. If the only pro for the first strategy is the ability to return a value, is the snippet I found considered poor programming since it is more difficult to read?

Comment: I think the biggest issue is just readability. It is much easier to look at the if statement and figure out what is happening.

Comment: If you love Star Wars, Yoda code is always great, putting the string in front of the typeof check in front of the assignemnt etc.

Comment: I always think of [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using &&'s short-circuiting as an if statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049006/using-s-short-circuiting-as-an-if-statement), [Difference between “if (foo) bar();” and “foo && bar();”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907997/difference-between-if-foo-bar-and-foo-bar) and a few others

Comment: That actually looks much like minified code. Are you sure you're reading the actual source file?

Comment: This is just confusing and unnecessary IMO.  I am all about terse code but not just for the heck of it.

Comment: @Bergi Does minification convert if statements to this format?

Comment: @user3439515: I remember some minifiers to do that, yes - it saves characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just want to point out there are less clear uses of this idiom and more clear.

```
"string" != typeof myVar && (myVar = "");
```

I read this and actually had to convert it to if/else in my head. Steve McConnell argued there shoud be one line of code per work, which I tend to agree with and which this is in ludicrous violation of. Also note that embedded side-effects are risky in the first place, this is pretty egregious.

```
parameters = parameters || {};
var speed = parameters.speed || 60;
```

is IMO a much clearer use, partly since it's such a well established idiom. or

```
if(x && x.employer && x.employer.company === 'google')
```

is a clear use of the idiom (you'll get an exception if you do `undefined.company`, for instance).

Comment: I want to learn this syntax and other usefull, shortening the code with &&. What shall I type to find it ?